# problem with quotes send variable in double quotes php

Tags: php

```
if($d == 'c'){
$query .= " example = '$example' ";
```

hi I am trying to send the variable  $example in double quotes and not single quotes

i get this after run the query

```
example = 'test@test.com'
```

Comment: [Didn't you ask this already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61278696/update-the-data-that-the-value-is-an-email-but-in-braces-mysql-php)

Comment: If this is for SQL, as the other question shows, this looks like a SQL injection hole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the statement in single quotes, then use the double quotes as you normally would. Then concatenate the variable using periods with a closing and reopening single quote.

```php
$query .= 'example = "'.$example.'" ';
```

You can also escape the double quotes as well.

Using a backward slash to escape the double quotes:

```php
$query .= "example = \"".$example."\" ";
```

PHP Manual on escape sequences: 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Comment: thanks I worked the first option at the beginning I was trying as well as you did but I did not run through the double quotes at the beginning